# Combining string in forEach() loop fails

Tags: java, string, foreach

I have some basic code that is supposed to format an input string. The input string has a list of words, separated with a newline. My code is supposed to add to add a few chars to the beginning and end of each line. ("\"-" in the beginning and "\"," in the end.) However, although each element in the list is printed correctly when printing separately, the var 'out' does not contain all the elements, instead it contains "\",\"".

```
String[] split = everything.split("\n");
    String out = "\"";
    for (String split1 : split) {
        System.out.println(split1);
        out = out + "-" + split1.toLowerCase() + "\",\"";
    }
    System.out.println(out);
```

For example, for the input string:

```
Indonesian\nid\nYiddish\nyi
```

prints:

```
Indonesian
id
Yiddish
yi
","
```

when it should print:

```
Indonesian
id
Yiddish
yi
"-indonesian","-id","-yiddish","-yi","
```

Can someone explain what is causing this behavior and how to fix it?

Update:
I did some more testing. It seems if i simply set `everything` to `Indonesian\nid\nYiddish\nyi`then the desired output comes out. However, `everything` is read from a big text file. I pasted the contents of the file here: http://pastebin.com/Tjf9dzcb

I read the file like this:

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\Users\\xxxx\\Desktop\\hi.txt"));
    String everything = null;
    try {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = br.readLine();

        while (line != null) {
            sb.append(line);
            sb.append(System.lineSeparator());
            line = br.readLine();
        }
        everything = sb.toString();
    } finally {
        br.close();
    }
```

Comment: Nope, java is not broken, see https://ideone.com/HFPsNd

Comment: +fge Sorry for the confusion. The last line of the output should be all lowercase. (The other lines should not)

Comment: Even if your 'everything' string is empty, I fail to see how you can get the output you mention. Are you sure this is all of the code?

Comment: +fge I did some more testing. It seems if i simply do `everything = "Indonesian\nid\nYiddish\nyi"` then it works. However, `everything` is read from a txt file, the contents of which are here: http://pastebin.com/Tjf9dzcb

Comment: Try changing the split to `everything.split(System.lineSeparator())` instead of `\n`.

Comment: Funny, for me the code works pretty well.

Comment: How you read from file?

Comment: Are you reading from the file one line at a time? ;-) I don't think you posted your actual code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use both `sb.append();` and `everything.split()` with same parameter.

```
sb.append("\n");
String[] split = everything.split("\n");
```

Or

```
sb.append(System.lineSeparator());
String[] split = everything.split(System.lineSeparator());
```

**EDIT**

Definition of `System.lineSeparator()` in [JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#lineSeparator%28%29)

> Returns the system-dependent line separator string. It always returns the same value - the initial value of the system property line.separator.
>   On UNIX systems, it returns "\n"; on Microsoft Windows systems it returns "\r\n".

So if your system is Windows then `System.lineSeparator()` is equivalent to  `"\r\n"`. In UNIX your previous code should work well.

Comment: Yup. Or change the input routine: `sb.append('\n');`

Comment: This somehow worked :D I however, don't understand how. Does '\n' != System.lineSeparator()? If so how was i able to use a for-each on the output of .split()?

Comment: Yes for Windows but No for UNIX. It's better to use System.lineSeparator() when needed.

Comment: On Windows, System.lineSeparator() == "\r\n". So there was a '\n' in there for the split to use. But there was that extra '\r'. That's a Carriage Return. (The '\n' is a Line Feed.) And Carriage Return means "move the cursor all the way to the left". There's your hint, I think.